# Java Enum data long value being set to zero

Tags: java, enums, primitive-types

Given the enum below,

```
enum SizeUnits {

    Bytes(1),
    Kilobytes(1024),
    Megabytes(1024 * 1024),
    Gigabytes(1024 * 1024 * 1024),
    Terabytes(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024),
    Petabytes(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
    private final long multiplier;

    private SizeUnits(long mult) {
        this.multiplier = mult;
        System.out.println("mult="+mult);
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
mult=1
mult=1024
mult=1048576
mult=1073741824
mult=0
mult=0
```

Obviously, the last two are clipping somewhere internally and I don't understand why. It doesn't look like it should, given that I'm using a `long` and the [claimed max value for long with Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is:
`2^64-1`.

If it was clipping at the size of an integer, I would have expected it to clip 1073741824 as well. Also, it's not simply wrapping around, but actually clipping the values to zero.

Why does it clip the last two entries to zero?

### Update:

Ah. The type of the literal. Of course.

Note (as mentioned by answers below) if I put the `L` as the last entry of the line, it still overflows for the larger case, as obviously it hasn't promoted the operation to `long` prior to the overflow.

Now it makes sense why it didn't work when tried to cast it via

```
(long)(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)
```

But this works:

```
(1024 * 1024 * (long)1024 * 1024 * 1024)
```

It's a matter of when it overflows. Thanks all!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last two overflow. They are equal to `2^40` and `2^50`
which does not fit into an int. These are ints, not longs.
Add `L` to the first of the `1024` values:

`Terrabytes(1024L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)`

When you add `L` you say explicitly that it's a long.
Then the other operands are also promoted to long,
and the result will not overflow.

Try also:

1) `long x = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;`
2) `long y = 1024L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;`

See what values you get in `x` and in `y`.

Comment: Both x and y will print 0. y overflows before you get to the long.

Comment: To extend what Peter said, in Java, all integer numeric constants are assumed to be int, unless you suffix them with 'L', to indicate that they are to be treated as long.

Comment: To expand upon Peter's answer: Even though your constructor parameter is of type long, your numeric literals are all of type int. Java doesn't automatically cast the *result* of integer multiplication to a long as part of the calculation step. By adding 'L' to one of your numeric literals you are now telling java to multiple an integer by a long which does cause automatic, loss-less type conversion.

Also, FYI "Terrabytes" has only a single 'r' in it ("Terabytes"). Thank the IntelliJ spellchecker.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan OK, thanks, I will investigate this further. Fixed this part in my answer so that it's correct now.

Answer (score 2):

What your are calling "clipping" is numeric overflow.  Your are repeatedly multiplying (`int`) powers of two until they overflow.  Because only the lower 32 bits are kept, you get `0` because the only bit that would be set is beyond the lower 32.

When you have the gigabytes value (1024 * 1024 * 1024), you are already at 2^30 in an `int`:

```
01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

When multiplied by another 1024, you would get this if the precision allowed:

```
1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

But only the lower order 32 bits is kept, which is `0`.

You can cast the first `1024` to a `long` or use a `long` literal.  (It needs to be the *first* literal to ensure `long` arithmetic the entire way and avoid intermediate overflow.)

```
(long) 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024

1024L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
```

A `long` has 64 bits, enough for your purposes (2<sup>50</sup>).  However, if you keep going and you need values larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`, 2<sup>63</sup>-1, then switch to using `BigInteger`s.

Answer (score 1):

You are only converting the result of the calculation to a long.  Any multiple of 2^32 will overflow to 0.

Another way to write what you have is

```
enum SizeUnits {

    Bytes(1L << 0),
    Kilobytes(1L << 10),
    Megabytes(1L << 20),
    Gigabytes(1L << 30),
    Terrabytes(1L << 40),
    Petabytes(1L << 50),
    Exabytes(1L << 60);
    private final long multiplier;

    private SizeUnits(long mult) {
        this.multiplier = mult;
        System.out.println(name() + ": mult=" + mult);
    }
}
```